# how to change column header, such as sum(FREQ) to FREQ, in mysql?

Tags: mysql, header, sum

I did

```
create table A as select sum(FREQ) from B;
```

so I got table A with field name sum(FREQ). I tried to change the column header with this code:

```
alter table A change sum(FREQ) FREQ bigint;
```

but it didn't work

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give an alias `FREQ` in the select list:

```
create table A as select sum(FREQ) as FREQ from B;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alter table A change column `sum(FREQ)` FREQ bigint;
```

Comment: I checked in my database its work fine. Have you checked?

Comment: I did. :( hm maybe I did something wrong then lol
Thank you anyways!